# soapclient request is incomplete

Tags: php, soap

I am using php SOAPClient to call data from an external server, and have tested and verified the service using soapUI.  My request seems to work correctly until it hits the fourth parameter, which is a string (the first three are numbers). My code and the request are below:

```
$wdsl = "http://ofmpub.epa.gov/WATERSWebServices/SpatialServices?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($wdsl, array(
                                "trace"=>1,
                                "exceptions"=>0));
$lat =  46.852783;
$long = -114.004517;
$radius = 1;
$program = '303D';

$values = $client->getEntitiesByLatLong($lat,$long,$radius,$program);
```

The resulting request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ofmpub.epa.gov/WATERSWebServices/SpatialServices.wsdl">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getEntitiesByLatLong>
      <latitude>46.852783</latitude>
      <longitude>-114.004517</longitude>
      <searchRadiusMiles>1</searchRadiusMiles>
      <programsList />
    </ns1:getEntitiesByLatLong>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I believe the service is expecting a string here.  Is there something I have done wrong with the code?

Comment: Looking back through the documentation, it looks like it's expecting stringArray, so I have changed $program  to : array('303D');. The tag appears complete: <programsList><ns2:String>303D</ns2:String></programsList>, but there is no response.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you need to pass an array or object to the soap client method call.
i.e.

```
$data = array('latitude' => 46.852783, 'longitude' => -114.004517, ... );
$values = $client->getEntitiesByLatLong($data);
```

The keys from the array or properties from the object are mapped to the xml nodes & values accordingly.

On the soap client object, you can get the request xml & actually see what is being transmitted over the wire (using getLastRequest()) [php soap client](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)